# how to select from database and populate in a text box on Vb. net

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have a mini project to update a stock in the database and I want to make sure if the product exist in the database it should display the product code in a textbox TxtCode.Text but it is not working. This is my code kindly help

```
Private Sub TxtCode_Validating(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs) Handles TxtCode.Validating
    con = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.Oledb.4.0; Data Source=" & Application.StartupPath & "\pharmacy.mdb")
    con.Open()
    Dim ct1 As String = "select code from stock where ProductName= '" & TxtPrdtName.Text & "', company= '" & CmbCompany.Text & "' and Type= '" & CmbType.Text & "'"

    Dim rdr As OleDbDataReader
    cmd = New OleDbCommand(ct1)
    cmd.Connection = con
    rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader()

    If rdr.Read Then
        TxtCode.Text = rdr("code").ToString


        If Not rdr Is Nothing Then
            rdr.Close()
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Please include the exact error message you are facing. "Not working" is useless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The different conditions applied to a WHERE clause should be linked together by an AND/OR logical operator.
Your code is missing the AND/OR operator between the first and second condition

However you should rewrite this to remove the string concatenation and passing to parameterized query approach.

```
Dim ct1 As String = "select code from stock " & _
                    "where ProductName= @prod " & _ 
                    "AND company= @cpy " & _ 
                    "AND Type=@typ"

Using con = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.Oledb.4.0; Data Source=" & _
                                Application.StartupPath & "\pharmacy.mdb")
    con.Open()

    Using cmd = New OleDbCommand(ct1, con)
       cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prod",TxtPrdtName.Text)
       cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cpy",CmbCompany.Text)
       cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@typ",CmbType.Text)
       Using rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader()
          If rdr.Read Then
              TxtCode.Text = rdr("code").ToString
           End If
       End Using
    End Using
End Using
```

Using a parameterized query helps to avoid Sql Injection (albeit a rare event in MS Access) but helps a lot in the clarity of your code. (look at how readable is now the sql command text) Finally, using a parameterized query shifts the work to quote your strings, parse your dates and interpret your decimals to the database engine.

Comment: Thank you Steve and Djukic. It as work,  when I add AND

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what exactly isn't working but your SQL statement is missing an AND.

```
Dim ct1 As String = "select code from stock where ProductName= '" & TxtPrdtName.Text & "' AND company= '" & CmbCompany.Text & "' and Type= '" & CmbType.Text & "'"
```